# Как сделать свзяь многие ко многим

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, many-to-many

У меня есть две таблицы: Books, Genre. Каждая книга может иметь неограниченное количество жанров. Между таблицами связь многие ко многим. Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно создавать третью связующую таблицу и правильно ли она создана?

```
CREATE TABLE book(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        genreToBook_id number
);

CREATE TABLE genre(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        bookToGenre_id number
);
    CREATE TABLE genre_to_book (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            book_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            genre_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT "FK_book_id" FOREIGN KEY ("book_id")
          REFERENCES "book" ("id"),
        CONSTRAINT "FK_genre_id" FOREIGN KEY ("genre_id")
          REFERENCES "genre" ("id"),
    );
```

Comment: Если у вас нет ограничения в используемом фреймворке, то суррогатный ПК в таблице `genre_to_book` не нужен. Вполне подойдет естественный (`book_id`, `genre_id`). Если же ПК из одного столбца необходим, то повесьте на пару (`book_id`, `genre_id`) ограничение уникальности (альтернативный ключ). В остальном таблица `genre_to_book` организована правильно.

Comment: А что за столбцы `genreToBook_id` и `bookToGenre_id`?

Comment: это внешний ключ к таблице genre_to_book, я так понимаю, он не нужен

Comment: Нет, в таблицах `book` и `genre` ссылка на `genre_to_book` не нужна и даже вредна.